# My model does not save data even from admin panel in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i create a app name order in it a model name order but when i tried to save some data in that model from the user view it doesn't save it then i tried to save it doesn't even got save from there i don't understand what causing the problem

```
    class BuyOrder(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
        address = models.ForeignKey(Address, default= True, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
        status = models.IntegerField(choices = status_choices, default=1)
        method = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False,)
        total_price = models.FloatField(blank=False, default=0)
        payment_status = models.IntegerField(choices = payment_status_choices, default=3)
        order_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200, null=True, default=None) 
        datetime_of_payment = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        # related to razorpay
        razorpay_order_id = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
        razorpay_payment_id = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
        razorpay_signature = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.order_id is None and self.datetime_of_payment and self.id:
                self.order_id = self.datetime_of_payment.strftime('COOLBUYORDER%Y%m%dODR') + str(self.id)
                return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                pass
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username + " " + str(self.order_id) + " " + str(self.id)
```

here is the screenshot of admin panel even from their i unable to save any data in that form
[image]

i tried everything migrate zero change the app place the model and remove the previous still doesn't understand what causing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your save override method

```
if self.order_id is None and self.datetime_of_payment and self.id:
```

This condition will never happen because self.id will always be None in case of saving new object to database because it's auto-generated from the db.

You've 2 options I think.

1. Add new field UUID and set it as the Primary key instead of id
   2)Or just create the object and then update order_id
   You can use _state.adding

   ```
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
                is_adding = self._state.adding
                super( ).save(*args, **kwargs)
                if is_adding:
                             'add your if condition here'
                    self.save()
   ```

Comment: so how can i genrate a random order id for every order

Comment: I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have simply forgotten to pass the model to which you wish to call the super save method.

```
Your code :  super().save(*args, **kwargs)

solution:  super(BuyOrder,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

otherwise the save method will not know which model you wish to apply the change to.